# Execute a SQL Statement that Returns a Single Value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, subquery

I have a SQL select statement like this:

```
 SET @list = 'TEST,TEST1'
 SET @Delimiter = ',';
 SET @list =  @list + @Delimiter;

 SET @listIndexTemp = CHARINDEX(',',@list);  
 WHILE(@listIndexTemp > 0)
 BEGIN
    SET @listTemp = SUBSTRING(@list, 1,  @listIndexTemp -1);
    DECLARE @string VARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @string = 'SET @listTempUid = SELECT id FROM ['+CAST(@database as varchar(50))+'].[dbo].[MAIN] WHERE [name] = '''+CAST(@listTemp as varchar(100))+'''';
    EXEC (@string);

    INSERT INTO #Roles (uid, name) VALUES(@listTempUid, @listTemp);

    SET @list = SUBSTRING(@list, @listIndexTemp+1,  LEN(@list));
    SET @listIndexTemp = CHARINDEX(',',@list);

 END
```

For my case the above query is in a loop. Therefore, I have to assign the returned value from the above query statement 'string' to a SQL variable 'listTempUid' for each iteration.

The above query is not working. I have to add id and name into a temporary table for the corresponding name in the input list.

Please help

Comment: Possible post your procedure here.

Comment: updated code. Hope you can understand!

Comment: So what do you want?

Comment: The above query is not working.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by using `EXECUTE SP_EXECUTESQL` instead of `EXEC`. For using `SP_EXECUTESQL` you need to declare `@string as NVACHAR`. In the dynamic query, you have to assign value using `SELECT` instead of `SET` statement. And for getting value from Dynamic Query you have to use `OUT` parameter.

Try something like this.

```
 SET @list = 'TEST,TEST1'
 SET @Delimiter = ',';
 SET @list =  @list + @Delimiter;

 SET @listIndexTemp = CHARINDEX(',',@list);
 WHILE(@listIndexTemp > 0)
 BEGIN
    SET @listTemp = SUBSTRING(@list, 1,  @listIndexTemp -1);

    DECLARE @string NVARCHAR(MAX)

        SET @string = 'SELECT @TempID = id FROM ['+CAST(@database as
           varchar(50))+'].[dbo].[MAIN] WHERE [name] = '''+CAST(@listTemp as
           varchar(100))+'''';

            EXECUTE SP_EXECUTESQL @string, N'@TempID INT OUT', @listTempUid OUT

    INSERT INTO #Roles (uid, role) VALUES(@listTempUid, @listTemp);

    SET @list = SUBSTRING(@list, @listIndexTemp+1,  LEN(@list));
    SET @listIndexTemp = CHARINDEX(',',@list);

 END
```